# how would I find the nth term in a loop? java

Tags: java, loops

Here is a quick look at the program that I made to give a better example of my question.

**Loop code**

public void scheme1(int d) {

```
     // first modification
    if (mark<=20){
          System.out.print("\nBecause mark under 20 mark stays as its original value. mark="+mark);
          return;
    }
    int total = mark;
    int finalMark=20;

    System.out.print("Scheme 1"+"\n");

// Loop
    for(int loopParameter = START_CONDITION;
    loopParameter <= d;loopParameter++){
        System.out.print("(" + loopParameter + ") " + total + "   ");
    total = total + constantDiffSch1;

      // second modification
     
     if (total < 40){
         System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + loopParameter);
         return;
      }
    
      // third modification
      if (total<=20){
         System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
        return;
      }
}   // End
System.out.print("\n\n");
```

}

**This is what my program outputs**

> Please input mark: 64
>
> Please input number of days to display: 10
>
> Scheme 1
>
> (0) 64   (1) 59   (2) 54   (3) 49   (4) 44
>
> This work can be up to 4 days late before failing.

**This is what the output is supposed to be**

> Please input mark: 64
>
> Please input number of days to display: 10
>
> Scheme 1
>
> (0) 64   (1) 59   (2) 54   (3) 49   (4) 44   (5) 39   (6) 34   (7) 29   (8) 24
>
> This work can be up to 4 days late before failing.

I have to display how many days late the assignment is and calculate the late penaltie (mark -5) I also have to display the number of days needed needed to fail the assigment ( number of days until failure might be larger than the number (d) of days that the user input ) . the failing mark is less than 40.

**2nd example (output)**

> Please input mark: 64
>
> Please input number of days to display: 2
>
> Scheme 1
>
> (0) 64   (1) 59   (2) 54
>
> This work can be up to 4 days late before failing.

I have almost complete my code but this problem is slowing me down.

P.S. I am new at java

**here is my full program**

**LatePenalties calss**

```
public class LatePenalties {

    // attributes
    private int mark;

    private static final int constantDiffSch1 = -5;
    private static final double constantDiffSch2 = 0.9;
    private static final int START_CONDITION = 0;
    // constructors
    public LatePenalties(int m) {
        mark = m;

    }
    
    // methods
   
 public void scheme1(int d) {

         // first modification
        if (mark<=20){
              System.out.print("\nBecause mark under 20 mark stays as its original value. mark="+mark);
              return;
        }
        int total = mark;
        int finalMark=20;

        System.out.print("Scheme 1"+"\n");

    // Loop
        for(int loopParameter = START_CONDITION;
        loopParameter <= d;loopParameter++){
            System.out.print("(" + loopParameter + ") " + total + "   ");
        total = total + constantDiffSch1;

          // second modification
         
         if (total < 40){
             System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + loopParameter);
             return;
          }
        
          // third modification
          if (total<=20){
             System.out.print("\nBecause mark drops below 20, mark stays as 20. final mark="+ finalMark);
            return;
          }
    }   // End
    System.out.print("\n\n");
 }


 public void scheme2(int d) {
        double total = mark;

        System.out.print("\n\nScheme 2"+"\n");

    // Loop
        for(int loopParameter = START_CONDITION;
        loopParameter <= d;loopParameter++){
            System.out.print( "(" + loopParameter + ") " );
            System.out.printf("%.02f",total);
            System.out.print("   ");

        total = total * constantDiffSch2;
    }   // End
    System.out.print("\n");
 }
}
```

**Main class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LatePenaltiesUser {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    // local variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    LatePenalties latePen;
    int mark;
    int days;
    
    // input      
    do{
    System.out.print("Please input mark (between 0 and  100) --> ");
    mark  = input.nextInt();
    if  (( mark < 0 ) | (mark > 100 )){System.out.print("\n" + "Input value outside the range!!!" + "\n");}
    }while(( mark < 0 ) | (mark > 100 ));

    do{
    System.out.print("Please input number of days to display (between 0 and  20) --> ");
    days = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    if  (( days < 0 ) | (days > 20 )){System.out.print("Input value outside the range!!!"+ "\n");}
    }while(( days < 0 ) | (days > 20 ));

    // computation
    latePen = new LatePenalties(mark);
    latePen.scheme1(days);
    latePen.scheme2(days);

    }
}
```

I have to show when the faling mark occurs(at less than 40), but I have to stop the loop at 20 or when the number of days is reached, as I show in the example on what it is expected.

Comment: Do I get it right, that you basically just want to decrease the value of grade in each loop iteration and when the grade drops below 40 stop the loop?

Comment: I have to show when the faling mark occurs(at less than 40), but I have to stop at 20 or complete the number of days, as I show in the example on what it is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` to come out of the loop as soon as `total` is less than 40. You can update your `scheme1` method as below

```
public void scheme1(int d) {

        int total = mark;

        System.out.print("Scheme 1" + "\n");
        int days = 0;
        // Loop
        for (int loopParameter = START_CONDITION; loopParameter <= d; loopParameter++) {
            System.out.print("(" + loopParameter + ") " + total + "   ");
            total = total + constantDiffSch1;

            if(total < 40)
                break;
            days++;
        } // End
        if (total <= 40) {
            System.out.print("\nThis work can be up to " + days +" days late before failing.");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
```

> Please input mark (between 0 and  100) --> 82
>    Please input number of days to display (between 0 and  20) --> 10
>
> Scheme 1 (0) 82   (1) 77   (2) 72   (3) 67   (4) 62   (5) 57   (6) 52 
>   (7) 47   (8) 42
>   This work can be up to 8 days late before failing.

Comment: I have to show when the faling mark occurs(at less than 40), but I have to stop at 20 or complete the number of days, as I show in the example on what it is expected. @iNan

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know your `loopParameter` to calculate the number of days. You can calculate it like so:

```
int days = (d - 40) / -constantDiffSch1;
```

You can use `break` when you want to quit loop. So:

```
if (total < 20) break;
```

And off topic. Don't call `loopParameter` like that. It is good practice to call it in one symbol (or short word) like `i` or `day`. It makes code easier to read and understand.